# Associate a division with a case

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

We have two sub-divisions in our company and one team for each company. Thing is we do not want a division to be able to see the cases of the other. Nothing very complicated here.

My problem is that an account associated with a division should be by default the same associated to its cases...whoever created the case (from one team or the other).

Is that possible? If so, could you give me a hint?

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSCRM does this out of the box with Business Units. Read up on BUs and security at Technet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328427.aspx

Doing it yourself via plugins is almost certainly the wrong way to do this.